# Splitting an array in list for two parts in C?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, quicksort, partition

I have a linked - list that contains an array.
I need to implement a quicksort algorithm [with pivot] which splits the array into two parts:

The first is a left-mini array which contains all the elements from the beginning of the original array to the middle,
and the second one is a right-mini array that contains all the elements from the end of the original array to the middle

My question is, how can I split an array from a list?

Do I have to make two copies of the original array and do memory allocation in order to make two new arrays?
Is there a more simple way to do that?

Here's my code so far: (the part that implementing the quicksort function)

```
list* support_array;
support_array = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
support_array = (*lst);

while (support_array != NULL)
{
    i++;
    support_array = support_array->next;
}

list* leftarray;
leftarray = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));

list* rightarray;
rightarray = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
```

Comment: Appology about the wrong tagging. 
The linked list using is according to homework exercise requirements

Comment: What is it with linked lists and quicksort lately? You don't want to `malloc` anything, because you don't create new nodes when sorting; you just shuffle the existing nodes around. And if you `malloc`, don't throw the handle to the memory away in the next line as you do for `support_array`. For what it's worth, [I've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72144631/2979617) to a similar question recently. You might find one of the answers there useful.

Comment: Because it is contiguous, you only need a pointer to the first element and the length to define a [sub-]list; as the previous comment, you do not need to copy anything.